# angular and socket io -- clearing a notification in navbar

Tags: angularjs, sockets, socket.io

I have a navbar li with a notification count (similar to facebook newsfeed). it is for a stream that is being sent real time data with socket.io.  the expected behavior is that when you click on the stream, the notification count is cleared (set to zero).  It is all working as expected (unfortunately, I got it work with $rootScope), and when you click on the li in the navbar for "stream" it gets set to zero.  however when you add something to a recipe box from the home page (something io is listening for from all users), the notification count picks up where it left off and gets incremented to 1 + the previous count, rather than 1 + 0.  I tried a bunch of different things client side but it simply doesn't work.  1) how can I get it work 2) what's the "angular way" of approaching this problem? Thank you! Including my code per some comments.

socket.io code:

```
io.on('connect', function(socket) {
    // here you are adding socket connections to the sockets array
    sockets[socket.id] = socket;

    console.log('GOT CONNECTION: ' + socket.id);

    //getting event from client side
    socket.on('lasthouractivity', function () {
      console.log('GOT EVENT: lasthouractivity  FROM: ' + socket.id);
      //query the database.
      BroadCastLastHourActivity();
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function (socket) {
      console.log('SOCKET DISCONNECTED: ' + socket.id);
      delete sockets[socket.id];
    });
  });

  function BroadCastLastHourActivity() {
    var anHourAgo = moment().subtract(1, 'hour');
    RecipeStream.find({
      createdAt: {
        $gt: anHourAgo
      }
    }, function (err, recipes) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err, recipes);
        recipes = [];
      }
      //sending message back to client. can have same name but can be different.
      for (var s in sockets) {
        sockets[s].emit('lasthouractivity', recipes);
        console.log('SENT lasthouractivity RESULT TO: ' + s);
      }

    });
  }
```

navbar:

```
</div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li data-match-route="/$"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li data-match-route="/add"><a href="/#!/add">Recipe Box <span class="badge">{{recipeBox.recipeCount}}</span> </a></li>
            <li> <a href="/#!/stream" ng-click="clearCount()"> Stream<span class="badge">{{data.count}}</span> </a> </li>
        </ul>
```

stream html:

```
div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Activity Feed</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row show-list">
                <div class="fade-repeat col-xs-4 col-md-3" ng-repeat="recipe in lasthourRecipes ">
                    <p>
                        <!-- dont display upvotes if -->
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
      ng-click="incrementUpvotes(item)">{{upvotes}}</span>
                        <img ng-src="{{recipe.image}}">
                        <br>
                        <a href="{{recipe.recipeUrl}}" target="_blank">Recipe Link</a>
                        <div>
                            Recipe added by {{recipe.userName}} : 

                        </div>
                        <br> {{recipe.name}}
                        <br> {{recipe.numServings}}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="addthis_native_toolbox"></div> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

stream controller:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
//we have the Stream/Socket.io service is in vendor/socket.min.js "socketFactory"
.controller('StreamCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.data = {};
  $rootScope.data.count = 0;
  $scope.lasthourRecipes = [];
  $scope.upvotes = 0;
  $scope.incrementUpvotes = function (item) {
    $scope.upvotes++;
  };

  //TODO: comments/emojis.

  socket.emit('lasthouractivity');
  socket.on('lasthouractivity', function (response) {
    //this gets the recipeStream model
    $scope.lasthourRecipes = response;
    console.log(response);
    // get the right scope
    $scope.$apply();

  });
});

navbar controller:

angular.module('MyApp')
  .controller('NavbarCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, Auth, Profile, RecipeBox) {
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.logout = function () {
      Auth.logout();
    };

    $scope.clearCount = function () {
      $scope.data.count = 0;
    };
    // function updateStream(){
    //   socket.emit('lasthouractivity');
    //   // console.log('emitting an event');
    // }

    // setInterval(updateStream,10000);

    socket.on('lasthouractivity', function (response) {
      $scope.data.count = response.length;
      // console.log("got a response");
      // console.log(response);
    });

    $scope.recipeBox = RecipeBox;
    $scope.streamActivityLength = $rootScope.streamLength;
    // console.log(RecipeBox);
    //watching the currentUser property on rootscope
    //when it does, get the name from the profile.

    $rootScope.$watch("currentUser", function (newValue, oldValue) {
      if (newValue) {
        $scope.message = "Hi, " + Profile.getName() + "!";
      }
    });
  });
```

there is also a main controller which calls many methods in the recipes service. the recipes service does a bunch of $http gets and posts.

Comment: There's no way to know what's wrong with your code without seeing it.

Comment: You are representing the stream as an array in angularjs, right?

Comment: Could you please post your sample in something like plnkr.co

Comment: @devdropper87 just a suggestion . if your nav controller get destroyed any rootscope events attached to it dosent get destroyed. You would have to manually de-register them. having rootscope events lying around might cause issues.

Comment: @devdropper87 how is your data.count set again? listening to socket events?

Comment: get @Sudheer thanks I will definitely have to look in to that for your first suggest. for your second question, towards the end of the last snippet of code, this is where it's being set:  socket.on('lasthouractivity', function (response) {
      $scope.data.count = response.length;
      // console.log("got a response");
      // console.log(response);
    });

Comment: @devdropper87 does your nav controller gets initiated multiple times during the application? if so you would need to remove the socket listeners whenever the controller is destroyed. is your count always multiple times to the value?